# Спрайты в меню на главной странице

Tags: спрайт

Вот есть 2 файла html 1-index стандартный и 2 - меню c CSS. Как можно вставить меню т. е. код из 2 файла в 1 файл в блок меню, чтобы вместо ссылок работали кнопки со спрайтами (и в них потом ссылки на другие разделы)?[1 файл html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ziunv.jpg)
[image: sprite]

Создал ещё файл 3.css a {
  display:block;
  width:185px;
  height:52px;
  background: url('3.css');
}
a:hover {
  background-position:0px -52px;
}
a:active {
  background-position:0px -104px;
} и добавил ссылку a href="3.css">3css

в меню 1 файла, в итоге на странице отображается 3css как ссылка  и в ней открывается код  файла

Comment: Может, https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html поможет? простой в освоении.

Comment: а о чём он? у меня в принципе получилось-подключил css стиль в шапке html, но кнопки прыгают теперь( хотя в отдельном другом файле всё нормально